# Can I differentiate a timeout from a message size issue using only CommunicationException?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-binding, wcf-client

Folks,

I hit the following exception and I know for a fact that its not a timeout issue and that its a message size issue.  Using ONLY the CommunicationException, is there a way to tell that this issue was a message size issue and not a timeout issue?  Perhaps one of the properties on CommunicationException?  or maybe it can be cast in a certain way?  I'm willing to explore any proposals.

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '24.11:30:00'. ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '24.11:30:00'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, Message& message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Comment: Are you sure? Could it be a timeout exception _because_ the length of the data? As, naturally, more data means a longer trip.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure.  The timeout is 24 hours.  I ran this thing 8 hours ago. =)

Comment: If the length of the data is invalid (i.e. longer than is supported by the binding) then you would get a `FaultException` with a message something like: `The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data`

Comment: Also, I know that the message size on the return message is huge in this case, bigger than my previous test cases and would easily break the limits I've set.

Comment: you sure?  http://nerdwords.blogspot.com/2008/01/wcf-error-socket-connection-was-aborted.html

Comment: Hmm, maybe this has something to do with the configuration, do you push fault details down the wire, or is that disabled? If disabled, then maybe this a generic error you're seeing, of sorts.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the quotas? If so and that still isn't working, you could try adding this to the `<behaviors><endpointBehaviors>` node: 

`<behavior name="EndpointBehaviour">
   <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
 </behavior>`

Comment: note that my question is about detecting the quota failure, not about fixing it (correct, I'll just increase some of the quotas to fix the issue).  I'm trying to write some better error-handling code.

Comment: btw - another approach to this is possibly to list out all the possible reasons why communication exception is thrown...maybe there's a difference in the Message property?

Comment: I'm just trying to give you options to firstly help determine the real nature of the error - as I'm not initially convinced it is as you thought.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a good way to do this.